# Java i18n too much lines

Tags: java, internationalization

I have a Java program and I'm using i18n

```
public class ListNames extends ListResourceBundle implements ListNamesInterface {

    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return new Object[][] {
               {"ALPHA", "Alpha"},
               [...
           }
}
```

but Eclipse says me this:
`The code of method getContents() is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit`.

I have understood that the method is too much long, but I cannot know how to split it.

The row number of `Object[][]` is 100.000 lines.

Have you an idea to do it?

Comment: Can you load the data from an external file instead?

Comment: I cannot. I have tried to use the proprieties but I have some problems so for this reason I have decided to use this approach.

Comment: You have problems with this approach too, though :) Can you explain the problems encountered with the properties file approach?

Comment: The project use this approach and my managers cannot switch on prosperities.

Comment: Having 10k things specified in Java code is not a good approach. If your management is tying your hands, take this problem to them, say this approach can't be used because of a solid technical constraint, and ask them how they want it to be done.

Comment: Well, you _could_ try and split your contents into multiple files, i.e. classes that return parts of the array, and assemble everything into a big array and return this. But I would definitely suggest you try to go for properties files first and if you aren't allow to do so then it might help to understand the reasons for that.

Comment: Have you an example to merge two or more `Object[][]` ?

Comment: It is very common to provide ResourceBundle entries as a .properties file (which the ResourceBundle.getBundle methods will automatically read as a PropertyResourceBundle).  A .properties file probably will not have the same length limitation.  That said, do yourself, developers, and localizers a favor, and break it up into multiple smaller ResourceBundles.

Comment: I have asked, but there are some problems about the encoding of properties files. Because the project will be run on several different servers even very very old servers. And some of them cannot accept some encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit size of a method is 65535 byte, but you can define as many methods as you need to join as a large array. Obviously you could use ArrayList / addAll / toArray in place of `System.arraycopy` here to build longer arrays:

```
protected Object[][] getContents() {
    Object[][] contents1 = getContents1();
    Object[][] contents2 = getContents2();
    // You will need to repeat above many times to make 100,000 rows...

    // Then join up the arrays:
    Object[][] merged = new Object[contents1.length+contents2.length][]; // add more
    System.arraycopy(contents1, 0,merged, 0, contents1.length);
    System.arraycopy(contents2, 0,merged, contents1.length, contents2.length);
    // etc

    return merged;
}
```

Having said that, the above is a terrible way to implement this when property resource bundle files are available to you.

I cannot recall using any JDK or OS combination on which Property bundle did not work effectively, so you have probably not investigated the alternative and much easier solution.

Comment: I thank you very much. I have done some tests and on ´file.java` I can put the cyrillic alphabet but not on properties files.

Comment: As of JDK1.6 `Properties` and `PropertyResourceBundle` can be loaded using a Reader. Thus you can enforce handling your own .properties (or .xml) files in any character set you wish and edit the contents in a sensible editor. This is much easier than editing a pre-JDK1.6 ISO8859 format properties file that uses escape encoding of non-ISO8859 characters (which is hard to use).